# Javascript/JQuery: Add text box when select list/dropdown value is "other"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a form that has several select lists including the value "Other".

I need to write a Javascript/JQuery function that inserts a textbox if the value === "Other", and then saves the value of the field as what is in the textbox when the form is submitted. I'm getting stuck on how to implement this. It cannot of course use and ID as there will be at least two inputs on the page that need to use this function.

I'm currently trying to make it work using a class, here is the code I've got:

```
function doSomething(){
  if($(".selectlist :selected").text() === "Other"){
    $(".selectlist :selected").add("<input type=text></input>").appendTo(document.body);
  }
}
```

This kind of works, but as you'll see it pulls the "Other" value out of the select list as it creates the input. I've heard about `event.target` and using `this` or `$(this)`, but I don't have much experience in JQuery and my scrolling through the JQuery documentation hasn't done much to help me, I've been faffing with `.append()`, `.appendTo()`, `.add()` etc. but I'm going in a bit blind

(It's not permissable in this case to just hard code an output and show/hide it depending on the select value)

Any ideas welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
function DoSomethingOnChange(selectBox) {
    if ($(selectBox).find(":selected").text().trim().toUpperCase() == "OTHER") {
        $('.other-input').show();
    }
    else {
        $('.other-input').hide();
        $('.other-input').val(""); //clear out the value if required
    }
}
```

when triggered through an inline event handler such as:

```
<select  onchange="DoSomethingOnChange(this)">
<option></option>
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
<option>Other</option>
</select>
```

provided one of your options has the text *other* written.

```js
function DoSomethingOnChange(selectBox) {
  if ($(selectBox).find(":selected").text().trim().toUpperCase() == "OTHER") {
    $('.other-input').show();
  } else {
    $('.other-input').hide();
    $('.other-input').val("");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="DoSomethingOnChange(this)">
  <option></option>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Other</option>
</select>

<input class="other-input" hidden type=text placeholder="Other input" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work

```
$("select").each(function(i,obj) { 
    if ($(obj).val() === "Other") {
        $(obj).parent().append("<input type=\"text\" name=\"" + $(obj).prop("name") + "\" />");
        $(obj).remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myDropdown').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 'other') {
      $('#otherTextBoxContainer').show();
    } else {
      $('#otherTextBoxContainer').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="myDropdown">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>

  <div id="otherTextBoxContainer" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" id="otherTextBox" placeholder="Please specify" />
  </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: because this answer properly work